# ORA-00920: | unabale to set INTERVAL via ibatis

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ibatis

Ok, so after researching a lot still I couldn't find the answer

Below is the SQL query that I am trying to execute through ibatis

```
<select id="selectSQL" parameterClass="String" resultMap="get-resultMap">   
     SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SYSDATE - INTERVAL #value#  DAY > LAST_UPD_DTIM
 </select>
```

This throws an error

```
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

but when I hard code the interval value it works fine

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SYSDATE - INTERVAL '90'  DAY > LAST_UPD_DTIM
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Is #value# treated like a bind variable or is the actual value substituted in? If the latter what is the actual value - does it include the single quotes?

Comment: Did you try `${value}`

Comment: @NullPointerException Is your problem solved ?

Comment: @09Q71AO534, $ is supported in myBatis and I am using iBatis (v2.5), so it doen't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, So finally I found the issue. The issue here was the expression

```
INTERVAL -'90' DAY
```

is a literal, so we cannot replace a part of it with a variable (parameter)

To fix this I used function [NUMTODSINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)

```
<select id="selectSQL" parameterClass="String" resultMap="get-resultMap">   
   SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL(#value#, 'DAY') > LAST_UPD_DTIM
 </select>
```